# Apply xsl to multiple element with same name?

Tags: xml, xslt

i am facing a problem while apply xsl on xml. the xml is having same name "item" for hotel, roomresponse and dailyrate. how do i resolve this issue?

here is the xml request,

```
<availableHotels enc:itemType="ns1:hotel" enc:arraySize="7" xsi:type="ns1:hotelArray">
    <item xsi:type="ns1:hotel">
        <processId xsi:type="xsd:string">HZ-51743575</processId>
        <hotelCode xsi:type="xsd:string">INHEYT</hotelCode>
        <availabilityStatus xsi:type="xsd:string">InstantConfirmation</availabilityStatus>
        <totalPrice xsi:type="xsd:float">275</totalPrice>
        <totalTax xsi:type="xsd:float">0</totalTax>
        <currency xsi:type="xsd:string">USD</currency>
        <boardType xsi:type="xsd:string">Room and Breakfast (Buffet)</boardType>
        <rooms enc:itemType="ns1:roomResponse" enc:arraySize="1" xsi:type="ns1:roomResponseArray">
            <item xsi:type="ns1:roomResponse">
                <roomCategory xsi:type="xsd:string">Standard Twin Room</roomCategory>
                <paxes enc:itemType="ns1:pax" enc:arraySize="2" xsi:type="ns1:paxesArray">
                    <item xsi:type="ns1:pax">
                        <paxType xsi:type="xsd:string">Adult</paxType>
                        <age xsi:type="xsd:integer">30</age>
                    </item>
                    <item xsi:type="ns1:pax">
                        <paxType xsi:type="xsd:string">Child</paxType>
                        <age xsi:type="xsd:integer">5</age>
                    </item>
                </paxes>
                <totalRoomRate xsi:type="xsd:float">275</totalRoomRate>
                <ratesPerNight enc:itemType="ns1:dailyRate" enc:arraySize="2" xsi:type="ns1:dailyRateArray">
                    <item xsi:type="ns1:dailyRate">
                        <date xsi:type="xsd:date">2012-02-25</date>
                        <amount xsi:type="xsd:float">138</amount>
                    </item>
                    <item xsi:type="ns1:dailyRate">
                        <date xsi:type="xsd:date">2012-02-26</date>
                        <amount xsi:type="xsd:float">137</amount>
                    </item>
                </ratesPerNight>
            </item>
        </rooms>
    </item>
</availableHotels>
```

xsl i have used,

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <Property>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="//availableHotels/item"/>1
        </Property>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="item">
        <Rooms>
            <Room>
                <Rate>
                    <Nights>
                        <xsl:apply-templates select="ratesPerNight"/>
                    </Nights>
                </Rate>
            </Room>
        </Rooms>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="ratesPerNight">
        <Night>
            ????????
        </Night>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Expected o/p:

```
<Property>
    <Rooms>
        <Room>
            <Rate>
                <Nights>
                    <Night Amount="6825.00" BookedDate="2012-02-25"/>
                                    <Night Amount="6825.00" BookedDate="2012-02-26"/>
                </Nights>
            </Rate>
        </Room>
    </Rooms>
</Property>
```

please help me to find out the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible to specify attributes on templates:

```
<xsl:template match="item[@xsi:type='ns1:dailyRate']">
</xsl:template>
```

This will only match those items... hope it helps

Actually, leave out the 'xsi:' 
Here is more code to get you started

```
    <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="utf-8" indent="no"/>
      <xsl:template match="/availableHotels">
        <Property>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="item/rooms"/>
        </Property>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="rooms">
       <Room>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="item"/>
       </Room>
    <xsl:value-of select="@type"/>
    </xsl:template> 

    <xsl:template match="item[@type='ns1:roomResponse']">
     <xsl:value-of select="totalRoomRate"/>
     <xsl:value-of select="@type"/>
    </xsl:template>



    <xsl:template match="item">
     <xsl:value-of select="@type"/>
    </xsl:template>                                             

    <xsl:template match="*">
     <xsl:value-of select="name()"/>
    </xsl:template>
```

The last template is very useful to capture the ones you have missed.

Answer (score 0):

You can not go into ratesPerNight because it's not a direct child of item. In your XSL you match it with `<xsl:apply-templates select="ratesPerNight"/>` inside item.
What you need is to either put the explicit path there as `<xsl:apply-templates select="rooms/item/ratesPerNight"/>`, or if you want to find all ratesPerNight elements without fixing the path you can use `<xsl:apply-templates select="descendant::ratesPerNight"/>`.